# Facebook API Realtime Updates issue with USER table

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using Facebook API **Real-time Updates** for **online_presence** field in **user** table , here is the php code I used.

Reference: 
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/01/31/how-to--subscribing-to-data-changes-using-the-real-time-updates-api/,

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  `db_name`.`table_name` (`value`) VALUES ('Test');");

  $verify_token = 'spydertest';

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET' && isset($_GET['hub_mode'])
    && $_GET['hub_mode'] == 'subscribe' && isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])
    && $_GET['hub_verify_token'] == $verify_token) {
      echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  `db_name`.`table_name` (`value`) VALUES ('Subscription Test');");

  } else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $post_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $obj = json_decode($post_body, true);
    // $obj will contain the list of fields that have changed
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  `db_name`.`table_name` (`value`) VALUES ('$post_body');");
  }
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

And here is Realtime Update settings of my Facebook application

[image]

Subscription test is successful and also Real-time Update working fine for **friends** field and got the callback when I add or remove friends, but **online_presence** field is not working when I change user's or friends presence.